# Common Lisp Break-If-There-Is-Error Macro-Wrapper (with Clack webserver)

Tags: macros, common-lisp, break

I am trying to write a macro that would wrap a form or several forms into its body and attempt to execute them. I would like the macro to drop into the debugger, similarly to how it happens when `(break)` is executed.

The problem is that I am not familiar with Common Lisp's tools for catching errors. What functionality of CL can I use to make this happen?

**Example usage:**
`(break-on-error (start '#:blogdemo :port 8080))`

Comment: Entering the debugger on error is the default behavior, you do not need to do anything special.

Comment: Not necessarily. Sometimes errors do not go into debugger. I noticed that when I run this webserver, it gets an Internal Server Error which I would like to investigate.

Comment: Then you will have to be much more specific because you are asking about a highly unusual behavior. E.g., what software you are running, what platform, copy-paste messages &c &c.

Comment: If you are using [Hunchentoot](https://edicl.github.io/hunchentoot/), then you can change the default value of `*catch-errors-p*` and `*show-lisp-errors-p*` (see the [documentation](https://edicl.github.io/hunchentoot/#*catch-errors-p*)).

Comment: On error handling: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/error_handling.html but indeed, your question is how to handle errors with your webserver. There may be settings to ignore errors and display a 404 (prod settings), display the backtrace in the browser or catch errors with the debugger. See [clack-errors](https://github.com/eudoxia0/clack-errors) (not needed with Snooze).

Comment: Thanks @Ehvince. I found a setting on the web server, as you suggested. Speaking of Clack, do you know of an example implementing RESTful API using Clack and/or Lack? I found basic tutorials for those but am not sure how to do more complex stuff. The latter is particularly true for Lack.

Comment: No I don't, it is still a field to explore… do you use Clack/Lack directly or use a web framework ? I tried Caveman, Lucerne, and lastly really liked [Snooze](https://github.com/joaotavora/snooze): a route is just a function, accessing query parameters is obvious, they are the function arguments (when it is tedious with Caveman), it has built-in settings to choose where to catch errors (no need of clack-errors). By the author of Sly (and yasnippet and more), not much used. What are the more complex stuff you want to do besides an endpoint and json output ?

Comment: Well, I would like to build RESTful end-points or at the very least HTTP ones that can distinguish the verbs. Thus far, it has been a bit of a moot point. I have been using Clack or Hunchentoot directly.

Answer (score 3):

The above comments are correct: the webserver can probably be configured to stop catching and logging errors, and break instead.

But note that [`BREAK`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_break.htm) is guaranteed to always enter the debugger, and you can always bind a new handler around a form you want to test. For example, suppose you have this handler that catches errors and log them to standard output:

```
(defun main ()
  (handler-case (my-function) 
    (error (e) 
      (print `(:error ,e)))))
```

Also, let's define `my-function`:

```
(defun my-function ()
  (if (zerop (random 2))
    (print "success")
    (error "failure")))
```

If you call `main` several times, you will see either `"success"` or an error being printed to standard output.
If you want to break when `my-function` fails, despite the handler being established in `main`, you can redefine `my-function` as follows:

```
(defun my-function ()
  (handler-bind ((error (lambda (condition) (break))))
    (if (zerop (random 2))
      (print "success")
      (error "failure"))))
```

The style is not great (the condition is ignored, etc.), but this is only for debugging, after all.
And now, the function will enter the debugger on error.

You can write a macro for that. First, define our handler as an external function (for reuse, etc. Also, the less code in the macro, the better). By the way, this time, the condition is not ignored, it is printed to the user.

```
(defun break-on-error (condition)
  (break "~a" condition))
```

The macro is then simply:

```
(defmacro with-active-debugger (&body body)
  `(handler-bind ((error #'break-on-error))
      ,@body))
```

The function can be rewritten:

```
(defun my-function ()
  (with-active-debugger 
    (if (zerop (random 2))
      (print "success")
      (error "failure"))))
```